# Trying to rotate an image with JS when an element contains a certain class

Tags: javascript, image, web, rotation

Basically im trying to make it so that when i click on a question the arrow i have next to the question rotates 180 degrees. Right now my code doesnt rotate the arrows at all.
Any help would be appreciated.

Heres my javascript code

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

var img = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow");

if (button.classList.contains(active)) {
  img.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
}
```

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE7ge.png)

Comment: You need to put your condition in the `onclick` event listener, no?

Answer (score 1):

One big reason this isn't working is that this line:

if (button.classList.contains(active)) {
img.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
}

isn't inside of some function that triggers the arrow to rotate. It is evaluated when the page loads and then not used again. However, there are a few ways to improve your code.

Using classes to affect your style changes allows you better readability, flexibility and reusability.  I also opted for `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByClassname` and used a `closest`/`querySelector` combo to find adjacent elements rather than nextElementSibling

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".accordian").forEach(acc => {
  acc.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.target.classList.toggle("active");
    e.target.closest('.container').querySelector('.arrow').classList.toggle('active')
    e.target.closest('.container').querySelector('.content').classList.toggle('show')
  });
});
```

```css
.arrow {
  transition: all .5s;
  display: inline-block;
}

.arrow.active {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <a class='accordian' href='#'>click me</a>
  <span class='arrow'>></span>
  <div class='content'>Show//Hide content</div>
</div>


<div class='container'>
  <a class='accordian' href='#'>click me</a>
  <span class='arrow'>></span>
  <div class='content'>Show//Hide content</div>
</div>
```